# Stripe Button & Non-Stripe Button in same form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to do payment processing for ticketed events on my site.

Clients have an option to let their customers pay by cash or check so I've added a button for that (since stripe doesn't take $0 payments).

I want to have 2 submit buttons within a single form (where other input is being taken as well) where 1 is a stripe button and the other is one that allows a "deferred payment."

However, when clicking the non-stripe button, the stripe popup appears.

[**FYI:** with free events, when the price is $0, the stripe button is suppressed and processing works as expected with my 2nd button.]

I've looked for examples that might have this setup but haven't found one.  I also asked Stripe directly and they didn't provide a real answer.

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the form?

Comment: I made a fiddle here:  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pcartagena/dz6r4wb9/10/)  I took out my test key so an error is occurring that doesn't normally happen.